# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError while installing gems

Tags: rubygems, openssl

The gem seems failing to install any gem on my Linux, I'm not sure what's cause of the problem.
Below is the debug message while installing mongo gem, it gets plenty of repeated "OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError" error messages, any idea what might be wrong?

```
$ gem install --debug mongo
```

---

```
Exception `Gem::LoadError' at /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296 - Could not find 'rdoc' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s)
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:323 - File exists - /home/user/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%443
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError' at /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb:174 - read would block
Exception `OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError' at /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb:174 - read would block
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, the following worked for me:

```
$ rvm remove 2.0.0 # get rid of unsuccessful installation
$ rvm get head --autolibs=3 # get the latest RVM and build required libs
$ rvm requirements # just in case, install all other required stuff
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
$ rvm --default use ruby-2.0.0
```